# CakePHP: Trouble calling all data from a specific table row

Tags: mysql, database, cakephp, rows

I've searched the cookbook for an answer to this, and I'm stumped. I feel like it should be a pretty simple solution.

I am following the Blog section in the cookbook, only I added two additional rows to the table. An "author" row and a "category" row. However, when I attempt to call the data nothing is returned to the view.

Here's the model code:

```
<?php

class Post extends AppModel {
    public $validate = array(
        'title' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty'
        ),
        'body' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty'
        ),
        'author' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty'
        ),
        'category' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty'
        )
    );
}
```

Here is my controller code:

```
public function index() {
    $this->set('posts', $this->Post->find('all'));
    $this->set('title_for_layout','jotliet.com development blog');
}
```

Here's the view code:

```
    <?php foreach ($posts as $post): ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $post['Post']['id']; ?></td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $this->Html->link($post['Post']['title'], array('action' => 'view', $post['Post']['id'])); ?>
    </td>
    <td>
         <?php echo $post['Post']['author']; ?>
    </td>
    <td>
         <?php echo $post['Post']['category']; ?>
    </td>

    <td>
        <?php echo $this->Form->postLink(
            'Delete',
            array('action' => 'delete', $post['Post']['id']),
            array('confirm' => 'Are you sure?'));
        ?>
        <?php echo $this->Html->link('Edit', array('action' => 'edit', $post['Post']['id'])); ?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $post['Post']['created']; ?>
    </td>
    <td>
         <?php echo $post['Post']['body']; ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

The "created," "title," and "body" rows return just fine. But "author" and "category" return nothing.

I've tested the model, controller and view code in multiple different ways. And I even messed with the database itself in phpMyadmin under the assumption that my table itself was faulty. No results.

I feel like this must have a simple solution. thanks guys.

Update:

I ran a print_r($posts) and it returned this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Post] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [title] => blah
                    [body] => blah
                    [created] => blah
                    [modified] => blah
                )
        )
```

No "author" or "category" to be found. How can I change this?

Comment: Try deleting model cache. delete all files in app/tmp/cache/models/

Comment: @nitin better to simply delete all files under `app/tmp` (cache problem -> delete all tmp files, it's a simpler rule to follow) e.g. `rm app/tmp/*/*`